# what is the difference between these two codes. One return error and second one return no error?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, constants, var, let

When I use var in the loop I get no error.

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  for (var reversedStr = "", i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedStr += str[i];
  }
  return reversedStr;
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"))
//OUTPUT --------> olleh
```

when I use let in the loop I get an error.

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  for (let reversedStr = "", i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedStr += str[i];
  }
  return reversedStr;
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"))
//OUTPUT -------->Uncaught ReferenceError: reversedStr is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoping.

In your first example, `var reversedString` is function-scoped, and accessible in the whole function.

In your second example, `let reversedString` is block-scoped, and only accessible **in** the `for` loop.

Comment: And that is an easily found dupe.

Comment: If the answer is more complicated or different to the documentation, then I will also answer a dupe. This however not.

Comment: I wasn't talking about you, tho.

Comment: I figured that out after doing the math ;)